# Multi-Dimensional Array in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array

I'm wondering if its possible to do multidimensional arrays in rails?

I'd like to get something like to formulate some data:

```
apple => 'tasty', 'red', 'round'
cereal => 'milk', 'breakfast'
name => 'tags'
```

Where I'm trying to get the name-value pair where the right side is tags so when I call the name, I can get tags.

EDIT:

I currently have this

```
@array = ['apple', 'cereal', 'name']
```

But would like to add tags to these

```
@array = ['apple'=>['tasty', 'red', 'round'], 'cereal' => ['milk', 'breakfast'], 'name' => ['tags']]
```

I wanted to do something like this, so when I do a loop to output only the names, and the associated tags.

Comment: Get from where? For what? That's not a "multi-dimensional array", it's a hash with array values, at least so far.

Comment: @DaveNewton I edited my question, maybe its more clear? I guess its not a multi dimension array yet, but would like to get some kind of basis, if I have to do more

Answer (score 1):

Like Dave Newton said above in the question's comments, it's called a hash, it's for things like `key => value`. Hash's can use Array's as values, Array's can use Hashes as values.

`{apple: ['tasty', 'red', 'round'], cereal: ['milk', 'breakfast'], name: ['tags']}`

Comment: No, you need to put the curly braces around it `{` and `}` instead of normal array ones. If you have the `=>` you need curly braces. E.g. `@array = {'apple'=>['tasty', 'red', 'round'], 'cereal' => ['milk', 'breakfast'], 'name' => ['tags']}`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called `Hash`, whose element are key-value pair. The key should be is `string` or `symbol` ;the value could be any object.

In you specific case, `apple` is the key, and `['tasty', 'red', 'round']` is the value.

Check out this [link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html) for more about Hash in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of YAML? You can put your data in YAML format in a file, read it in, and it automatically will create your hashes and arrays for you:

```
apple:
   - tasty
   - red
   - round
cereal:
   - milk
   - breakfast
name: tags
```

and then in ruby:
    require 'yaml'

```
file=YAML.load_file(filename)
file.each_pair do |key, value|
   ...etc
```